# Local Admin changes for installing or changing IP

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2, administrator, group-policy

Good afternoon all.  We have a user here that installed a CAD program on his computer as a trial.  The user has local admin rights to the computer because he has to be able to change his IP address when he connects to a different VLAN out on the shop floor.  Is there a way to either:

1. Revoke local admin rights but give rights to change his IP address at will
2. Keep local admin rights and revoke ability to install programs

I look online and everything is all about giving users ability to install programs and I want to do the opposite.  Any ideas?

Comment: The permission to install programs is handled by a group policy, so why don't you just give a normal user account, the ability to change the ip address which is also handled by a group policy.  As an administrator they can change the policy themselves so that wouldn't do much do.  *This is also should be a HR policy in addition to any software polices.*  [You can also just make him a PowerUser](http://serverfault.com/questions/525880/what-does-windows-7-local-group-power-users-actually-do)

Comment: Setup DHCP in all VLANs and control his IP for him?

Comment: I do but sometimes he also has to change his IP to communicate to the machines to something different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Network group on the computer and added him to that and removed him from Administrator.  Thank you

Comment: You should go through ALL of this group's polices and revoke any permission the user does not need.  Giving them the absolute minimum amount of permissions is Security 101.  The next thing the user might do is, access something they shouldn't, instead of just installing software they shouldn't.  The next time they could install malware unknowingly, and encrypt every single share they have access to, do revoke those permissions.  You should actually just duplicate the Network user group and then modify the permission on that group.